Gluing together the moduli stacks of elliptic curves over Z[1/2] and Z[1/3]?
I have a long-running desire to understand what is the "global" moduli stack of elliptic curves, as a stack over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.
Recently I was pointed to Katz and Mazur's book, and in my non-algebraic geometer's mind, it finally sunk in that if we can define the stack over two opens forming a Zariski cover, for instance $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac12])$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac13])$, then we can ask for descent data and paste these stacks together along $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac16])$. I should point out Brian Conrad's Math 248B: Modular Curves notes on level structures that correct some errors in Katz–Mazur, and gives lots of nice detail on Legendre structures and full level-3 structures, which is what I have in mind to use here.
This is the recipe I have in mind:

The moduli problems of Legendre structures and full level 3-structures are representable.

There should be groupoid schemes (and maybe even Hopf algebroids—the schemes of objects, at least, are affine I believe) over $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac12]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac13]$ presenting the stacks of elliptic curves over these respective rings.

Base changing to $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac16]$ there should a weak equivalence of these groupoid schemes - an equivalence of stacks, but it should be possible to be written out explicitly as a span of functors of groupoid scheme with suitable properties (internally fully faithful plus "surjective on objects" in a sensible fashion).

Coherence of this weak equivalence (mildly non-trivial, but ideally an exercise in converting between the different cubic plane curve representations of the universal curves)

...

Profit!


It may well be that instead of Legendre structures I should be using (full) level-4 structures, but I'm not wedded to getting $Y(4)$, unless it's really forced on me.
Is this how things should work? Despite periodically looking for a construction of the moduli stack over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ for some years, I've never spotted it (a symptom of my ignorance of the literature... mea culpa). So it might be that this is embarrassingly wrong, or else so painfully obvious no one bothers to write it down.
But (this is correct and) if there's a source that goes through even some of these steps, I'd really like to know what it is!

Over Z[1/6] one should, I hope, be able to equip a curve that has full level 3-structure with a Legendre/level 4-structure, and vice versa. The forgetful functors should supply the span of groupoid schemes. Or, alternatively, some kind of level 12-structure construction? Hmm

Are you trying to find a description of the stack as a finite quotient stack, I.e., a quotient of a scheme by a finite group action?

@Jason no. As any (explicit as possible) groupoid scheme.

Isn't there a global description via Weierstrass equations? I'm thinking of the description on page 8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6100.pdf

@AchimKrause maybe! But precious few sources come out and say this, if so. It's all putzing about with level structures. Perhaps it comes down to what sort of stack one wants to build?

@Jason actually, that's over-simplified. Perhaps I want a DM stack, not an arbitrary algebraic stack. This might be the source of the tension between the simple description in the link Achim supplied, and the immense effort in eg Katz–Mazur (and Conrad). Thoughts?
